# How can I fix the number counting from 0 to 100 in php

Tags: php, math, serial-number

Suppose I have an array like that

```
$test= array(5,4,8,9,3,7,2,10,1);
```

Now I'll print them

```
foreach($test as $key => $value){           
    echo "<ul><li>$value</li></ul>";
}
```

but I want my output will be all numbers showing serially like

```
1
2
3
4
5
7
8
9
10
```

then how ill filter them and how can I get that kind of output?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: You shouldn't create a new `<ul>` for each element. Create one `<ul>` and then put each value in `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to sort:

```
  <ul>
  <?php
    $test= array(5,4,8,9,3,7,2,10,1);
    sort($test);
    foreach($test as $key => $value){           
      echo "<li>$value</li>";
    }
  ?>
  </ul>
```